# Does Ubuntu have drivers for almost all the vintage PC's?

Tags: drivers, support

I recently tried to install Ubuntu on old toshiba core2duo laptop through offline method and the process went smooth. A friend of mine also installed it on PowerMac G5 PC which is 90's PC so I am wondering if these offline installer pack support (device drivers) for allmost all array of devices?

Comment: Ubuntu no longer supports *ppc* architecture; only *ppc64el* which no Apple/Mac device is capable of running. Your friend is not using a *supported* version of Ubuntu on the PowerMac G5 PC I believe if you check (the oldest *standard supported* release is 18.04, and *ppc* is not an supported architecture for ESM releases).  I'm unsure what you're actually asking though; QA-testing is performed with & without internet (ie. online & offline) for almost all releases & architecture - but is this what you're asking as you're without specific details.

Comment: eg.  I performed a QA-test install on the box I'm using right now [*earlier today*]; however the install method I used is a re-install of a newer/later release that will auto-re-install all prior packages, without touching user files; but the install type requires re-installation of packages that aren't included on the ISO itself; thus internet is required for the install type I used. You gave no release, no product, or type of install etc.   Also FYI: this box is a core2quad (thus *amd64*) so rather like one c2d you mention too; but you didn't specify what you're after

Comment: @guiverc, ok if we limit the PC's/Laptops to say x86-64, there are plenty of devices that are out there, so say a display forexample may have WQHD, TFT with various screen size / resolution and come with or without frame buffer all need a very unique device driver and working out these unique drivers for individual device is quite challenging, yet Ubuntu got seemlessly installed in myraid of old devices (same installer) so my question is, does the install pack drivers for all these devices?

Comment: You've limited yourself to a single architecture which helps, however if you just choose Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; you can have install media (ISOs) that include the GA kernel stack, HWE kernel stack; and have options of kernels with 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 available.. The significance of the kernel stack (ie. kernel version) is that influences kernel modules included (ie. *drivers* are the commonly used name for kernel module), but 20.04 media does not exist with older kernels than 5.4; for that you need a different release....   ie. release matters, as well as ISO used (20.04, 20.04.2. 20.04.3..

Comment: @guiverc, my question is basically like MacOS comes with support to all its devices i.e. all types of drivers (LG, samsung manufactured display) so that you dont have to be connected to the internet to download unique drivers for unique devices such as iMac, macbook, MacPro etc. But the family of devices for Apple is reletively low compared to all the old PCs/Laptops like my 2002 model Toshiba Portege, which is tablet so I was surprised to see that the support for pen was there in Ubuntu in such an old laptop.

Comment: In QA-testing of releases up to Lubuntu 19.04/Xubuntu 19.04.. I used devices as old as from 2003... Those devices however were *i386* or 32-bit x86 and *disco* (19.04) was the last release with *i386* ISO media during development.  From 19.10 & later I use devices as old as from 2005, however I have times were some parts of an ISO don't react well with specific hardware; yet other ISOs (different kernel modules; even different packages sometimes) provide a better experience; giving work-arounds I can offer in support. Your answer could be YES providing you use an appropriate ISO for your box.

Comment: @guiverc ok please put this as answer and ill accept. It was bit weird that initially I installed Fedora and the bluetooth device support was not there for that old laptop, then when I installed Ubuntu, the bluetooth worked! So it looks like a cumbersome job of writing device drivers for say thousands of unique devices! And a single x86-64 ISO packing all these unique drivers for these myraid of devices! Technically Fedora is supported by RedHat and they are quite large company to miss the support for that particular bluetooth device while Ubuntu included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu no longer supports *ppc* architecture; only ppc64el which no Apple/Mac device is capable of running. Your friend is **not** using a *supported* version of Ubuntu on the PowerMac G5 PC I believe if you check (*the oldest standard supported release is 18.04, and ppc is not an supported architecture for ESM releases*).

I'm unsure what you're actually asking though; QA-testing is performed with & without internet (ie. *online & offline*) for almost all releases & architecture.

eg. I performed a QA-test install on the box I'm using right now earlier today (*a c2q rather like c2d you mention*); a 2008 dell optiplex; however the install method I used is a re-install of a newer/later release that will auto-re-install all prior packages, without touching user files; but **that install type requires re-installation of packages that aren't included on the ISO itself; thus internet is required for the install type I used**.

If you just choose Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop; you can have install media (ISOs) that include the GA kernel stack, HWE kernel stack; and have options of kernels with 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 available.. The significance of the kernel stack (ie. kernel version) is that influences kernel modules included (*ie. **drivers** are the commonly used name for kernel module*), but 20.04 media does not exist with older kernels than 5.4; for that you need a different release.... ie. release matters, as well as ISO used (20.04 & 20.04.1 use GA & 5.4 kernel, 20.04.2 uses 5.8 HWE. 20.04.3 uses 5.11 HWE, 20.04.4 uses 5.13 HWE, 20.04.5 uses 5.15 HWE)

In QA-testing of releases up to Lubuntu 19.04/Xubuntu 19.04.. I used devices as old as from 2003... Those devices however were *i386* or 32-bit x86 and *disco* (19.04) was the last release with i386 ISO media during development. From 19.10 & later I use devices as old as from 2005, however I have times were some parts of an ISO don't react well with specific hardware; yet other ISOs (*different kernel modules; even different packages sometimes*) provide a better experience; giving work-arounds I can offer in support.

**Your answer could be YES providing you use an appropriate ISO for your box.**

*An old example that may/may-not help; I had problems with old IBM Thinkpads r50p, t42p on 18.04.5 media so if I limited myself to that media using the 5.4 kernel I could respond Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was unreliable using those old IBM 32-bit thinkpads.  However an easy fix was just switch to the GA kernel stack (ie. 4.15) which receives full support for the life of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was my option I offered in support when I saw people mention problems.. If people wanted or needed to install/re-install; using 18.04 or 18.04.1 media resulted in a perfect system, or older 18.04.(2-4) HWE media worked providing it was offline, and the kernel stack switched to GA kernel before allowing the 4.18/5.0/5.3 HWE kernel to upgrade to 5.4... ie. something in the graphics of the old thinkpads didn't like the 5.4 kernel module (driver), but with 18.04 being a LTS release so kernel stack choices existed & switching stack was an easy workaround as the regression issue hadn't then been fixed*

*You also mention Fedora in comments & differences between Ubuntu/Fedora... When I started with GNU/Linux; I used to think one distribution was better for some hardware than others, as some would just install & work on old 32-bit devices; others wouldn't.  I no longer believe that; and believe all can be made to work equally once you work out the cause; as the differences between one distribution and another, which really are built from the same upstream sources, is just the age & the various components - so use your live media to explore & find one that works, once you've got that - it's easy to replicate that on the OS you really want to use.. I use Ubuntu of course, Debian, OpenSuSE, & Fedora - but to me they are all ~equivalent & basically the same; if I can get one to work on a box, I can get all to work!*

Comment: This makes sense also yes live media can check for compatible drivers based on hardware spec however, for offline ISO to work, it should pack drivers for ALL possible devices out there, which on its own means that people have gone through depths to generate drivers for quite wide variety of devices.

Comment: My other concern for asking such question was that I recently was playing around a linux distribution for MIPS gaming device. To compile the kernel I had to add configs in the make file and if I dont have driver for given LCD, then the display wont work! But in Ubuntu, it appears that the drivers for almost all the displays are available as till now I faced no issue in installing Ubuntu in old laptops (98 -2002)

Comment: With time, to prevent the kernel constantly growing in complexity (*dev* time), size (*compile* & *runtime* on user device) some kernel support gets dropped as other new devices get added.. so if you find support was added with a specific kernel, later kernels will usually  include it, until a discussion is held & consensus is to drop support for the [then] old rarely used device. To re-enable some devices may require only a recompile (with different setting) of the kernel, adding a module etc but backporting code from a different (later) kernel to earlier is a lot more work